# Establishing trust with a Shapeshifter

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, plot, fantasy

Alright, I can't figure out how to write a scene. I have a character that has never revealed the fact that she can turn into animals, not even to her family. If the character is planning to tell her confidant about this, what are some things she could do that would make the revelation just a bit easier for both the confidant and our shapeshifter.

*Edit: This is a world where magic, things that go bump in the night, and what not haven’t been revealed. The Shapeshifter, presumes that there are more like her, but has yet to find any more of her kind.

Comment: I would recommend the shapeshifter not to turn into a killer animal at first. Although that would make some hell of a scene :D

Comment: Is the reader aware the character is a shape shifter or are you revealing it to the reader as well?  In your subject, who is establishing trust in whom?  Character to character?  Reader to character?  Reader to author?  If this is a reveal to the reader, is it early in the book or late?  Is the character who can shift a main character/protagonist or a side character?  Is she a viewpoint character?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has a close vote; it certainly is not asking "what to write," but "how to write." As my answer below shows, this is seeking a writing technique, and I have provided one based in plausible psychology.

Comment: Does the confidant know that shapeshifters are a thing in the world in question? It would be a big difference between (a) learning that someone isn't quite who/what you thought they were, and (b) getting your entire worldview upended.

Comment: You might want to check out [What would be some realistic social reactions to a shapeshifter?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/6810/29) on [worldbuilding.se], if you haven't already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Have a conversation first.

Explain herself to her confidant, make it clear she IS a shapeshifter, and willing to prove it, until the person she is talking to demands a demonstration. Then provide the demonstration.

You can think of this as a form of intimacy, she has been keeping something about herself private. So write it similar to revealing a long held romantic attraction to another person: You don't typically announce that by taking all your clothes off, or trying to take theirs off, or even trying to kiss them if you are not certain they wish to be kissed in that moment.

You would approach it with talk, perhaps obliquely ("what do you think of shapeshifters?") or more directly.

You don't have to equate it too directly with romance (unless that helps your story), but the dynamic of the reveal is similar. The shapeshifter feels the reveal is necessary, but is fearful of how the reveal will change their relationship. She desires a more intimate level of interaction, but may be rejected and lose a friend.

It will be easier (on the confidant) if they are the ones that demand proof of this claimed shapeshifting ability.

Answer (score 2):

First, Shapeshifter would sit Confidant down and make them both [a nice cup of tea](https://robertcday.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/a-nice-cup-of-tea/). Then, when they were settled and chatting comfortably, she might start thus(ish)ly.

Shapeshifter: "Hey, Confidant, what's your favourite animal?" (big smile)

Confidant: "Erm, rabbit?"

Shapeshifter: "Cool - I like bunnies too! Hey, you remember that once upon a time we found out that Jeremy was a Shapeshifter and then we all lived happily ever after?" (anticipatory smile)

Confidant: "Yup, I remember that." (slurps tea)

Shapeshifter: "Well, watch this!" (turns into a rabbit)

Then paint a scene where Confidant chases the rabbit around the (rugged) room, catches it and then skins it for the pot. After all, it's dinnertime and, as she said, rabbit is her favourite meat!

Oh, wait - that wouldn't be so easy on Shapeshifter. Maybe skip the events of the previous paragraph.

So: comfortable surrounding, something good to eat/drink, happy preamble, an illustrative story where everything turns out good for all concerned and the grand revelation. The rest is just detail and yours will (of course) be different to mine.

Comment: What is the purpose of linking to your blog here (beyond, that is, trolling for visits)?

Comment: Hi, @Weathervane. I'd like nothing better than to be friends with you. If I have done something that you find offensive then I apologise. This is my third day on StackExchange so if I've broken a rule I'm unaware of then perhaps you could mark it down to naivete rather than maliciousness? I linked to my blog because it has an article on how to make a nice cup of tea. Are you in England like me? If so, I'd love to sit down with you and discuss it respectfully - perhaps over a nice cup of tea? ;)

Comment: Let's chalk it up to being a fresh face then ;) You may want to take a look [here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), where it says "Don't include links except to support what you've written.". The art of teamaking is related to your example, but not really to what the OP is asking. And no, not in England, but I do enjoy a nice cuppa ;)

Comment: Thanks for that link, @Weathervane and for your friendly winks - most appreciated. :)